# Assembly Tiva floating point unit enable

Tags: assembly, arm, keil, cortex-m, fpu

I want to use the Tiva LaunchPad TM4C123GH6PM Floating Point Unit and write assembly code for it in Keil uVision IDE (version 5). Below, I try to load 10 into the S1 FPU register. This gives me an unaligned access fault once it hits VLDR instruction, which is single precision.

I use Keil's startup code which main is exported to. I've tried multiple ALIGN values. The Coprocessor Access Control Register is set to full access. What else am I missing?

```
AREA    main,CODE,READONLY,ALIGN=2
THUMB   
EXPORT  main

__main    LDR    R0,=0xA
          VLDR   S1,[R0]

                 ALIGN
          END
```

Here is the TM4C data sheet I use: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf

Comment: `0xa` is decimal 10.  Loading a 4-byte float or 8-byte double from the address `0xa` is always going to be an unaligned access.  I suspect it's the data access, not the instruction, that's misaligned.

Comment: `VLDR   S1,[R0]` is probably trying to load value from address 10, not value from register. Unless there's `vldr s1,r0` variant, you probably have to store the value `10` into memory first, before you will be able to load it, and you need to reserve memory on aligned address then. (I have no knowledge of your actual CPU, so I'm just guessing form the source and error, how that syntax works, and I expect the direct `s1 = r0` instruction does not exist at all).

Comment: This comment assumes GCC; therefore, I'm not sure if applies to Keil. You  may try "vmov" then convert to float; e.g., vmov s11, r2   vcvt.f32.s32 s11,s11